# For Win8 app how do I schedule tile notifications/updates when on battery

Tags: notifications, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently scheduling a background task which then queues a number of tile updates. 
When the machine is on power, the background task will schedule the next batch of updates. I'm using a Maintenance type background task which does not run when on battery.
Most of the other types of background task types require the app to be pinned to the lock screen.

I need a background task to run periodically, to schedule the tile updates, including when on battery mode. The information being shown becomes out of date quickly, hence my requirement to frequently update the tile.

I also looked at TileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate tile updates but that requires a web service somewhere, my code is local in a background task.
It works as I want as a MaintenanceTask when the machine has power.

I'm pretty sure it is possible, I can see other apps updating when on battery mode, without being pinned.

How can I update tiles periodically (say every minute) regardless of being powered or on battery, from a background task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways an app tile can be updated on battery without the app being pinned to the lock screen. Two of the methods require a web presence: push notifications, and periodic notifications (which you mentioned). This MSDN article goes over each of the delivery methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx

If the content for tile notifications is not dynamic, scheduled tile notifications can be used. On each launch, an app can schedule some fixed number of tile notifications into the distant future. This MSDN article present an example app scheduling out notifications for a week in advance, and using both app launch and a timer background task to continually keep an app tile up to date:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761464.aspx

Comment: Your information is correct. I'm not having problems doing the update to the tile while on battery, that part works. I'm having problems executing the command that *schedules* the update. My updates to the tile happen once per minute. There is a limit of 4096 updates that can be set. That's a bit less than three days worth of updates. If the user turns off their device for three days and then turns on their device on battery, then my updates will have all missed their time and be stale. Being on battery I can not schedule further updates until they connect power as I'm using a Maintenance task

Comment: What are you doing that requires updates to the tile once per minute? The guidelines recommend that a tile should not be updated more than once every 30 minutes for non-personalized content.

Check out the "How often should your tile update?" section of this guidelines article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx

Comment: It's a clock. Kind of needs to be updated each minute or its out of date. There's already several apps in the store that do it. I'm going with a TimeTask, and asking user to pin to lockscreen. If they say no, it will still work but only when on power. Have to work with the limitation.

Comment: @StephenPrice: A clock does not sound like "personalized content", and it would fall unter the "once every 30 minutes" rule. Personalized content would be along the lines of instant messages or emails or something similar. A clock is like weather...general and non-personal. Hate to say it, but I would hope Microsoft would block the submission of an app that updated anything so frequently when it wasn't personalized content.

Comment: A rule created by Microsoft. I'm a user and I wanted a clock on the start screen. So being a developer, I wrote one. People are downloading it and even paying for it. Are the needs/wants of users wrong? Isn't the idea of customised apps the whole point of it? People (some) want to use their computers how they want. The don't want to be told. Just saying.